# Creating a main menu via XML for android app

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm kinda new to Android (Only started studying it this year at University) and am trying to set up a main menu for my app via XML.

Basically what I want is an 20% border around my four buttons.

The below code is what I have so far, it seems to work okay but I'm not sure if I've done it the right way or not?
Eclipse is currently giving me two warnings, one for the indented LinearLayout saying it might be useless, the other for the nested weights giving bad performance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want your 4 buttons together to take up 80% (each 20%) of the vertical space and be centered vertically?

Comment: Yeah, each button's height should 20% each and their width should be 80% of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is perfectly fine, eclipse gave you the warning about the layout beeing useless, only because you have two parent layouts, but you need them to be 2 to achieve what you want, by giving the weightSum=10 of the main parent layout,  and Weight=8 to the chid, making in 20% of border(not 80% but it's faily easy to manipulate)

Comment: Thanks and oopsy, meant 20% border hehe